# How to create dynamic crosstab in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, crosstab

I am going to create a crosstab using SQL Server. The crosstab requires with 3 specific names. Please following

I have the following table:

```
Location Company Month Year  Amount
A        ACO     11    2017  100
A        ACO     12    2017  101
A        ACO     1     2018  98
B        NAMO    11    2017  40
B        NAMO    12    2017  78
B        NAMO    1     2018  200
```

I want to create like following crosstab. The months will change based on user query but when changed to crosstab the months will be fixed like following:

```
Location Company   Month1 Month2 Month3
A        ACO       100    101    98
B        NAMO      40     78     200
```

but i don't need need like following which is usually used. My case is different

```
Location Company   11     12     1
A        ACO       100    101    98
B        NAMO      40     78     200
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crosstab Query with Dynamic Columns in SQL Server 2005 up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422901/crosstab-query-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005-up)

Comment: Are the column names actually "month1", "month2" and "month3"? If so, nothing dynamic is required... You only need dynamic SQL if the column names are required to reflect the actual months.

Comment: Thank you but in my example the column is always fixed month1, month2, month3 while the months values could change from 1 to 12.