# Microsoft Access Cross-tab Query - How to Convert to MSSQL View

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2016

Evening everyone.

I'm converting an Access Database to PHP and MSSQL.  I have a "Cross-tab" query that I use to list all the Account Managers and the sales they've quoted for and I get a query like the following:

[image]

To get this I use the following SQL:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(tblQuotes.priceToCustomer) AS SumOfpriceToCustomer
SELECT Clients.AccountManager
FROM tblQuotes LEFT JOIN Clients ON tblQuotes.clientID = Clients.ID
GROUP BY Clients.AccountManager
PIVOT Format([tblQuotes].[dateProducted],'yyyy-mm');
```

I've not managed to convert this query.  Can anyone please help.

Thanks in advance for any help given

Answer (score 2):

Access has "dynamic crosstab queries",  SQL Server doesn't.

You could use dynamic SQL like in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422901/crosstab-query-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005-up), but since you're changing the front-end too, you should probably just use a GROUP BY query and format the results for display in the front-end.  eg

```
SELECT c.AccountManager, 
       format(q.dateProduced, 'yyyy-MM') Month,
       Sum(q.priceToCustomer) AS SumOfpriceToCustomer
FROM tblQuotes q
LEFT JOIN Clients c
  ON q.clientID = c.ID
GROUP BY c.AccountManager, format(q.dateProduced, 'yyyy-MM')
ORDER BY c.AccountManager, format(q.dateProduced, 'yyyy-MM');
```

Answer (score 1):

David Browne is correct.  Perhaps you should consider moving this into the presentation layer.

That said, SQL Server is declarative by design.  This leaves either Dynamic SQL, which CAN NOT exist in a VIEW but can be called from a Stored Procedure ... OR ... a VIEW that would need to be expanded as the years pass.

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  (
        SELECT Clients.AccountManager
              ,Item  = left([tblQuotes].[dateProducted],7)  -- Assuming DATE and not DATETIME.  Otherwise use your Format([tblQuotes].[dateProducted],'yyyy-mm')
              ,Value = sum(tblQuotes.priceToCustomer)
         FROM  tblQuotes LEFT JOIN Clients ON tblQuotes.clientID = Clients.ID
         GROUP BY Clients.AccountManager
                 ,left([tblQuotes].[dateProducted],7) 
       ) src
 Pivot ( sum(Value) for Item in ( [2018-01]
                                 ,[2018-02]
                                 ,[2018-03]
                                 ,[2018-04]
                                 ,[2018-05]
                                 ,[2018-06]
                                 ,[2018-07]
                                 ,[2018-08]
                                 ,[2018-09]
                                 ,[2018-10]  -- Continue as Far as you like
                                ) ) pvt
```

**Or the Dynamic SQL**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From  (
        SELECT Clients.AccountManager
              ,Item  = left([tblQuotes].[dateProducted],7)  
              ,Value = sum(tblQuotes.priceToCustomer)
         FROM  tblQuotes LEFT JOIN Clients ON tblQuotes.clientID = Clients.ID
         GROUP BY Clients.AccountManager
                 ,left([tblQuotes].[dateProducted],7) 
       ) src
 Pivot ( sum(Value) for Item in (' + stuff((Select Distinct ','+QuoteName( left([dateProducted],7) ) 
                                               From tblQuotes
                                               Order By 1
                                               For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) pvt
'

Exec(@SQL);
--Print @SQL
```